# Change css class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change `class="active"` dynamically. when I click a link on otherlink.aspx then it should become active link. and when I click on default.aspx link then that should become `class = "active"`.

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1.aspx">Founder</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.aspx">Principal</a></li>
            <li><a href="link3.aspx">Sub-Principal</a></li>
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="otherlink.aspx">Departments</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="otherlink1.aspx">Departments</a></li>
            <li><a href="otherlink2.aspx">Courses</a></li>
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Please suggest me how should i do that?

Comment: How could you learn jQuery and not know about `addClass`, `toggleClass`, and `removeClass`?

Comment: They're all described here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because question displays a complete lack of initial research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose none of the links are causing a page refresh.
In that case simple way would be add a class to each link lets call it nav-links

```
<li class="active nav-links"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a>
```

then use jquery

```
$('.nav-links').on('click', function(){

//remove active class from old link

    $('.nav-links').removeClass('active');

//add active class to current link

   $(this).addClass('active');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

give ids to your li tags

```
<ul>
                        <li class="active" id="default"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="link1.aspx">Founder</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link2.aspx">Principal</a></li>
                                <li><a href="link3.aspx">Sub-Principal</a></li>
                                <li class="last"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id = "otherlink1"><a href="otherlink.aspx" >Departments</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="otherlink1.aspx">Departments</a></li>
                                <li><a href="otherlink2.aspx">Courses</a></li>
                                <li class="last"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
</ul>
```

in your otherlink1.aspx on load add these lines

```
$("li").find(".active").removeClass("active");
$("#otherlink1").addClass("active");
```

respectively in other asp pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in 3 steps (pseudo code):

1. *Loop* through all `a` tags

   1. *if* current `a.href` matches `window.location.pathname`

      1. `addClass('active')` to current `a.parent()` (the parent `li`)

Here it is in code (I have added an id to your list to make it easier to match in jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link1.aspx">Founder</a></li>
            <li><a href="link2.aspx">Principal</a></li>
            <li><a href="link3.aspx">Sub-Principal</a></li>
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="otherlink.aspx">Departments</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="otherlink1.aspx">Departments</a></li>
            <li><a href="otherlink2.aspx">Courses</a></li>
            <li class="last"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var current = window.location.pathname;
$('#menu a').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('href') == current){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

(maybe you need to strip the first / in `window.location.pathname`)